# rails view looks different when deployed on remote server

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my rails app, the look of my views differs depending on where it runs. If it's on localhost, the view looks as expected:
[image]

When running on the remote machine, it changes to this:
[image]

Both apps run in development-environment on WEBrick and all .css files are included in the asset-pipeline. Rails version is 4.1.7.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unfortunately forgot to add that I'm running ActiveAdmin too. When I did an inspect on one of the wrong displayed elements, I could see a lot of ActiveAdmin related css data next to my expected custom ones. Even though the active_admin.css.scss file is in */app/vendor/assets/stylesheets/* and not in */app/assests/stylesheets/*, it seems to affect my views anyway.

So far my application.css looked like this:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery.datetimepicker
 */
```

In order to isolate the problem, I removed the `*= require_tree .` completely and required the necessary default.css only. Now application.css looks like this:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require default.css
 *= require jquery.datetimepicker
 */
```

After reloading, everything looks exactly like on localhost now. While I can't explain why this configuration clutterd up my views, the new setting solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include this gem `gem "non-stupid-digest-assets"` in your `gemfile.rb` if didn't include it. Rails 4 have some issue with assets. Thanks

Comment: I included the "non-stupid-digest-assets" gem to my app, but it doesn't change anything. After deploying with capistrano and restarting the server, it still looks the same.

Comment: May be some css conflicts issue there. Can you provide url where I can check this?

Comment: I can't unfortunately give access to the page as it is a running on a clients machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the assets aren't loaded even when you think they are.  Try: `$bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

If anything is loaded here you should do another `git commit -m "Loading Assets for Prod" -a`  then deploy

Comment: I did run an assets:precompile. Everything loads faster, but still looks the same.